Old movie about mutating alien in a spaceship
So when I was about 10 years old (I am 27 today) I watched this movie with my mom which we don't know the name. It was about a big space vessel travelling through space (I don't remember why) but some weird mutating alien or substance got onboard. I remember scenes:

The spaceship got dark (they had to shutdown the eletricity, or the alien did). 
There was this guy wearing a red sweatshirt, with moderately long curly hair and beard, which seemed to be the leader or most proactive member of the crew.
Alien was very evil and could mimmick or distract the crew members.

Having watched the original Alien movie recently, it feels similar but it is not the same movie.
I already checked Supernova, it is not it.

The Lost in space reboot with Matt LeBlanc?  The mutating alien was doctor smith.

I think it might be Ice planet (2001). A guy wearing a red vest, with moderately long curly hair and beard appears in this movie.

In the brief period of peace after a terrible war in a far future Earth, an outer-space military academy is attacked by an unknown and unstoppable alien force. The commander along with a group of newly graduated cadets, escapes to a large research station. Pursued by the aliens, the station jumps through a mysterious hyperspace gateway that sends them to a planet in an unknown part of the universe. (letterboxd)

Wikipedia

Guy 27:00

No, it is not Ice Planet. As far as I remember, 90% of the movie is in the space vessel. The single, mutating alien, is infiltrated on the ship. The guy wearing read with moderately long hair does look similar, but he is older, looks a bit like Kurt Russell.

You didn't give a specific year, but could it be Mutant aka Forbidden World from 1982?




Pandorum (2009)? not that old but it fits some of the description
From rotten tomatoes:

Two astronauts awaken in a hyper-sleep chamber aboard a seemingly
  abandoned spacecraft. It's pitch black, they are disoriented, and the
  only sound is a low rumble and creak from the belly of the ship. They
  can't remember anything. Who are they? What is their mission? With Lt.
  Payton staying behind to guide him via radio transmitter, Cpl. Bower
  ventures deep into the ship and begins to uncover a terrifying
  reality. Slowly the spacecraft's shocking, deadly secrets are
  revealed, and the astronauts find their own survival is more important
  than they could ever have

